ChartJS Category Axis for line chart to behave same as bar chart
I have a chart which shows different datasets depending on what has been selected.
Some datasets are line charts and some are bar charts all using the same categories on the x-axis.
Now my problem is that the x-axis ticks are either start/end at the very beginning/ending for line-only charts but move to a center if there is at least one bar chart selected.
At least one dataset with bar-chart selected:

Only line chart selected:

This makes the chart ugly to use for users on selecting different datasets.
How can I tell ChartJS to behave the category x-axis behave the same for line-only charts to match the behavior for bar charts?
I'm using the current latest ChartJS version 4.4.3

You probably want to set scales.x.offset. Its default value is false, which places the first and last labels at the margins of the x axis. If however there is a bar chart, the default value becomes true which adds margins to the left and right of those labels. You may also play with the values for options.scales.x.grid.offset or options.scales.x.ticks.align

@kikon scales.x.offset works perfect. I was trying scales.x.grid.offset before but it wasn't giving me the expected results. THANKS!
PS: Feel free to send this as answer that I can accept ;)
